# Why does linkat require a path name instead of a file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux

The following code is taken from Debian's manual page `open(2)` from the paragraph describing the `O_TMPFILE` flag:

```
char path[PATH_MAX];
fd = open("/path/to/dir", O_TMPFILE | O_RDWR,
          S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

/* File I/O on 'fd'... */

snprintf(path, PATH_MAX,  "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd);
linkat(AT_FDCWD, path, AT_FDCWD, "/path/for/file",
       AT_SYMLINK_FOLLOW);
```

The idea behind the code is that you create an anonymous file, which has no name in the file system but just a file descriptor. This means nobody else knows about the file and can access it. Then you write the file. And in the end the file gets it name by `linkat`. After that the file is visible and everybody else can access it. This is an perfect way to treat download files in order to ensure that only a complete download file can be used by other programs.

But the way `linkat` has to be called looks broken by design to me. What does `linkat` effectively? It gives a file descriptor a name. This means the function needs two arguments: a file descriptor and a name. Instead it does not accept a file descriptor as an argument, but requires a name of the file, which does not have a name. This makes it necessary to rely on a mounted proc file system to create a name for the unnamed file in order to be able to pass that name to `linkat`. This looks so wired, that I have no idea, why someone invents this.

Why is it implemented in this way and why is there not just a function

```
link_what_ever (int fd, char *name);
```

Comment: As you wrote O_TMPFILE creates an anonymous file that nobody else knows about the file and can access it. This is what it does and, if info stored into that file have to be save, you can simply create your new file and copy the hide one into it. Linkat has not correlation with O_TMPFILE, it creates a new link (also known as a hard link) to an existing file.

Comment: Don't edit my answer to make a comment.

Comment: If my answer isn't working, what kernel version are you running? `AT_EMPTY_PATH` was added in Linux 2.6.39.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do what you want with the `AT_EMPTY_PATH` flag.

```
linkat(fd, "", AT_FDCWD, "/path/for/file", AT_EMPTY_PATH);
```

When this flag is used, it creates a link to the file identified by the `olddirfd` argument.

Note that using this flag requires the caller to have the `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` capability.

Answer (score 3):

From looking at the git history of Linux, at the beginning of August 2013 there was a [commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/bb2314b47996491bbc5add73633905c3120b6268) to unify the two interfaces thereby allowing an unprivileged `linkat(...,AT_EMPTY_PATH)`, but it was [reverted](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/f0cc6ffb8ce8961db587e5072168cac0cbc25f05) by the end of the month, citing unclear security implications in environments that do not mount `/proc`.

Answer (score 1):

> What does `linkat` do effectively? It gives a file descriptor a name.

No, your assumption is wrong: `linkat(2)`, just like `link(2)`, is designed to give a *new* name to a file (i.e. create a hardlink), it's a little bit different. It was not designed with the specific goal of giving a name to an anonymous file. Instead, it's a general purpose interface that allows you to create a new name `X` for the already-existing file `Y`.

You could argue that someone could implement another function `name_anon_file(int fd, char *name)`, and indeed that's true, but it's not so hard to implement it on top of `linkat(2)`, so you can do it yourself.

Plus, not every UNIX variant supports `O_TMPFILE`, so that function would not be of much use in the general case.

Comment: How can `name_anon_file` be implemented without a mounted proc file system?

Comment: @ceving It can't. Either way, if `/proc` is not mounted, you're in pretty bad shape - things like `ps(1)` and `lsof(1)` won't work.